# Adenosine metabolism

Tags: molecular-biology, immunology, enzymes

Are adenosine or its catabolites increased in inflamed airways? How can I assess this? I am trying to use inhibitors for adenosine deaminase, xanthine oxidase, and purine nucleoside phosphorylase, but I don't have a protocol.

Comment: do you want to measure these compounds ?

Comment: I want to see if Adenosine/ its metabolites levels at different inflammation levels of severerity

Comment: This depends on whose air way and what you are doing to inflame it.  Are you using a mouse model and having them huff LPS?